# In Python how can I find the matching elements in 2 tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

Let's say I have names as a list of tuples that contain some arbitrary string data:

```
tupl2 = ("a", "b", "c")
tupl1 = ("b", "c", "x")
```

How can get the result as

```
matching_elements = "b", "c"

not_matching_elements = "a", "x"
```

Comment: why is `'a'` a matching element?

Comment: it is typo.  that should be  matching_elements = "b", c"

not_matching_elements = "a", "x"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want the intersection and symmetric difference, you can get these easily (provided you don't care about order) using sets ...

```
>>> tupl2 = ("a", "b", "c")
>>> tupl1 = ("b", "c", "x")
>>> s1 = set(tupl1)
>>> s2 = set(tupl2)
>>> s1.intersection(s2)
set(['c', 'b'])
>>> s1.symmetric_difference(s2)
set(['a', 'x'])
```

Note, only the first actually needs to be a set -- The second can be left as a tuple...

```
>>> s1.intersection(tupl2)
set(['c', 'b'])
>>> s1.symmetric_difference(tupl2)
set(['a', 'x'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get the intersection in one line using a list comprehension:

```
matching = [item for item in tupl1 if item in tupl2]
```

The symmetric difference is a bit messier:

```
non_matching = ([item for item in tupl2 if item not in tupl1] +
                [item for item in tupl1 if item not in tupl2])
```

or:

```
non_matching = [item for item in tupl2 + tupl1
                if item not in tupl1 or item not in tupl2]
```

To be honest I'd probably use a `set` for the latter case, as in mgilson's answer.

Answer (score -1):

here is the my answer (modified)

```
          print set([x for x in list(tupl1 + tupl2) if list(tupl1 + tupl2).count(x) == 2 ])

          print set([x for x in list(tupl1 + tupl2) if list(tupl1 + tupl2).count(x) == 1 ])
```

Comment: Your second list comprehension will fail to return items that are present in `tupl1` but not in `tupl2`

Answer (score -1):

Matching?
Do you want to find consecutive characters ?
If my inference is true , here's your needed code :

## Matching Elements:

```
a=["a","b","d"]
b=["b","x","c"]
for index in  range(len(a)):
    i, ii = bytes(a[index],'ascii')[0], bytes(b[index],'ascii')[0]
    if i - ii == 1 or ii - i == 1 :
        print(chr(i), chr(ii))
```